# asp.net mvc create a database record

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

So, I've been trying to create a record.however I created it successfully but the problem is that I may need the ID that has been auto incremented.

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]

 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="CustomerServiceMappingID")] Maping serviceToCreate, FormCollection form)
    {


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)

                return View();

       var dc = new ServicesDataContext();
       dc.Mapings.InsertOnSubmit(serviceToCreate);
        try
        {
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```

after this, I tried to do this which has not been working

```
    var id = Int32.Parse(form["CustomerServiceMappingID"]);
        var qw = (from m in dc.Mapings
                  where id == m.CustomerServiceMappingID
                  select m.CustomerID).First();
      //  var id = Int32.Parse(form["CustomerID"]);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = qw });
```

Now I need to send Customer ID as a parameter to Index.. SO, can u help me out..

Thanks,

Comment: `serviceToCreate.Id` will be set after you do `db.SubmitChanges()`. Unless of course an error occured, which you'll never know because your swallowing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite as (dont exclude the ID from the parameter list - a particular reason this needs to be excluded?):

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(Maping serviceToCreate)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                return View();
        }

       var dc = new ServicesDataContext();
       dc.Mapings.InsertOnSubmit(serviceToCreate);
       dc.SubmitChanges();

      //try to get the values from 'Maping' model if possible?
       var qw = (from m in dc.Mapings
                  where m.CustomerServiceMappingID == serviceToCreate.CustomerServiceMappingId
                  select m.CustomerID).First();
       return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = qw });
```